# NSTextView not refreshed properly on scrolling

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextview, artifacts

I have a NSTextView with a sizeable quantity of text. Whenever I scroll however, the view isn't updated properly. There are some artifacts that remain at the top or the bottom of the view. It appears that the view doesn't refresh itself often enough. If I scroll very slowly the view updates correctly though. If I add a border to the view everything works perfectly, borderless view is the one that has a problem. Here's a link to a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone explain why has this question has been downvoted? It seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: dw I upvoted to counter :P +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you set the `setDrawsBackground` and `copiesOnScroll` propertes for either the `NSScrollView` or the `NSClipView`?

The first thing I would suggest is turning off the "draws background" property of the `NSScrollView`:

```
[myScrollView setDrawsBackground:NO];
```

Note that this should be set on the `NSScrollView`, and *not* on the embedded `NSClipView`.

The following excerpt from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsscrollview_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/setDrawsBackground:) may be relevant:

> If your `NSScrollView` encloses an `NSClipView` sending a `setDrawsBackground:` message with a parameter of `NO` to the `NSScrollView` has the added effect of sending the `NSClipView` a `setCopiesOnScroll:` message with a parameter of `NO`. The side effect of sending the `setDrawsBackground:` message directly to the `NSClipView` instead would be the appearance of “trails” (vestiges of previous drawing) in the document view as it is scrolled.

Comment: I just ran across this exact problem myself. Setting `[scrollView setDrawsBackground:YES]` fixed the artifact problem. In other news, it is a very strange feeling to find your own answer when searching for a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the text field isn't even in the scrolling-area... Are you sure something isnt overlapping it?

Comment: I'm not sure, no. If I scroll downwards though, the text will appear, aligned with the bottom of the scroll control. The garbage will disappear, replaced with clear rendering of the text.

Comment: did you try re-setting up your xib? Sometimes that helps me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar trouble - artifacts develop when the NSTextView is embedded in another scrollview (ie. a NSTableView).

I actually turned *on* the setdrawsbackground, and then added a nice color to make it disappear again.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    NSScrollView *scroll = [self enclosingScrollView];
    [scroll setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
    [scroll setDrawsBackground:YES];
    [scroll setBackgroundColor:[NSColor windowBackgroundColor]];
}
```

This in combination with a scrollWheel event let me use the NSTextView in a NSTableView.

```
-(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    NSScrollView *scroll = [self enclosingScrollView];
   [[scroll superview] scrollWheel:theEvent];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble some time ago. I don't remember how I solved it.

Try to place the NSTextView to another view if the superview is a custom view. Just to see what will happen.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Good to know that I'm not the only one with this problem though.